# Primary key in relational database while working with orm like sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-design, orm, sequelize.js

Currently I'm working in nodejs project where I'm using sequelize ORM to interact with Postgres database, so in database tables should I use custom fields as primary key while working with ORM like sequelize or just use autogenerated id , as we use auto generated id in non relational database like MongoDB.

Currently I'm using custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally much better to use an auto generated primary key. In PostgreSQL, it would look something like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <name> (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  <custom columns>
);
```

Using custom fields as a primary key can be a big problem if they end up being not unique (such as a name or date field) and they can be much harder to join.